# Need to learn the right way to use fonts colors on my site?

Tags: icons, color, typography

I want to learn web design to make good-looking websites. I have learned CSS, JavaScript, HTML quite well. But I need to be able to choose the right fonts, colors, backgrounds, images, etc. I want to learn typography and understand colors to apply CSS properly on my web pages and make them look good. Can somebody point me to the directions where i can learn it? May be UX is not the right place for this question. Please direct me in understanding this.

Comment: Graphic design might a good place for this question.

Comment: I shared some good resources on design here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/558/how-can-you-learn-to-design-nice-looking-websites/32484#32484

Comment: Sushil, your question is too broad. Per our FAQ, [If you can imagine an *entire* book that answers your question, you’re asking too much](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some interesting articles for you :

[The User Experience And Psychology Of Colour](http://spyrestudios.com/the-user-experience-and-psychology-of-colour/) - Very Good article which talks about how the use of color influences our basic emotions and interactions with artifacts on the internet.

[Colors and User Experience](http://blogs.infragistics.com/ux/articles/colors-and-user-experience.aspx) - This is a good article which talks about the impact of color with regards to visual appeal and the aspects which must be taken into consideration to account for color deficiencies

Here are some UX stack exchange questions you should look at :

[Using a secondary set of colors to indicate which elements of the UI can be interacted with](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/15505/5113)

[Are dark non neutrals colors suited for page backgrounds or is it more advisable to go for neutral colors like black or dark grey?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/16694/5113)

[What research, patterns or techniques will help me choose the correct colors (or saturations) to the various UI elements of a page?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/14269/5113)

Comment: When you post answers to bad questions, you set precedent for others to answer them instead of flagging or voting to close.

Comment: Maybe we could close this question,the reason I responded was because Visual design is part of User experience as well and I felt his question could be answered from an UX perspective

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the question is about UX or not. Such overly broad questions shouldn't be answered formally.

Comment: @dnbrv the question is overly broad because i dont have anything very specific here. I  am a absolute begineer in this field and needs directions. So what i should look,read try would be very much of a help. I need a starting point or otherwise i will always keep googling and hitting unneccesary links.

Comment: @sushilbharwani: Broad questions aren't in compliance with Stack Exchange's format. Quora is a much better place for such questions.

Comment: @dnbrv Interesting to know that, JeFF Joel your users are gonna move to quora :-)